# CV hyperparameter in sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've got a problem with understanding the CV parameter in cross_validate. Could you check if I understand it correctly?

I'm running ML algorithms in big set of data (train 37M rows), therefore I would like to run  a big validation procedure to choose the best model.

Using [ShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit), I want to build 100 different ways of splitting data in random way:

```
cv_split = model_selection.ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 100, test_size = .1, train_size = .9, random_state = 0
```

Then I want to use it as CV hyperparameter in [cross_validate](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html):

```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, X, Y, cv  = cv_split)
```

Does it mean that my Train set (X & Y) is divided into 100 random samples (each is then divided into: train (90% of sample), test (10 % of sample)) and during cross_validation model is built for each sample separetly (fitted on 90% of particular one/10 sample and tested on remaining 10% if this sample) and the mean prediction of those 100 models is the result? Also, if I am using Shaffle, does it mean that particular row can be in multiple samples and other will not be in any of them?

In other words, 37M set is devided:

- First Sample 370k XY1, 90% *3.7 = 333k rows as XY1_1(train), 37k as XY1_2 (test); model fitted on .fit(X1_1, Y1_1), predition is build on .predict(X1_2) and validated against Y1_2
- Second Sample 370k, 333k rows as XY2_1 and 37k rows as XY2_2; model fitted on .fit(X2_1, Y2_1), prediction built on .predict(X2_1) and validated against Y2_2
- etc

*I am not sure If the second explanation is more clear. But this is how I structure it in my head.*

I also read scikit.learn guide: [Cross-validation: evaluating estimator performance](http://3.1.%20Cross-validation:%20evaluating%20estimator%20performance) but I am still not sure

Comment: My post on KFold CV [HOW KFold works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063014/what-does-kfold-in-python-exactly-do/56052456#56052456) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this first:

> if I am using Shaffle, does it mean that particular row can be in
>   multiple samples and other will not be in any of them

If I've understood the question correctly, then yes, that is possible. See below:
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=.25, random_state=8)
rs.get_n_splits(X)
train = []
for train_index, test_index in rs.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

Output:

```
TRAIN: [1 0 3] TEST: [2]
TRAIN: [0 3 1] TEST: [2]
TRAIN: [1 3 0] TEST: [2]
```

Row `2` doesn't appear in any of the training sets.

Next, to answer your first question:

> the mean prediction of those 100 models is the result

Not quite. From the documentation (which you linked to):

> Returns: scores : dict of float arrays of shape=(n_splits,) Array of
>   scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.

Let's see this in action, on the above example:

```
from sklearn linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv = rs)['test_score']
```

returns

```
Out[36]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

So you see, it returns an array with the score on each cross-validation fold.

Comment: This is a great explanation and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!